# React js dont unmount a component on different paths

Tags: reactjs

this is my routes on app.js

```
<Routes>
        <Route path="/" element={<Dmall />}></Route>
        {/* <Route path="/random" element={ <Manga/>}></Route> */}
        <Route path="/search/:name" element={<Filter />}></Route>
        <Route path="/manga/:slug" element={<Manga  />}></Route>
        <Route path="/read/:slug" element={<Read  />}></Route>
        <Route path="/all" element={<ViewAll  />}></Route>
        <Route path="/top" element={<Top  />}></Route>
   
      </Routes>
```

i have another component inside manga and read called comment ths issue is i cant think of a way to if it is accessed from manga page to read page dont unmount comment component

```
<Link class=" bg-blue-500 hover:bg-blue-700 text-white font-bold py-2 px-4 rounded text-center" to={window.location.href.replace("/manga/", "/read/" )} state={{ pages: manga.pages, id: manga.id }}> {" "} Read Now </Link>
<div className="md:px-[2rem] px-4 md:mt-[6rem]"> {manga.id?
  <Comments mangaId={manga.id} />:""}
</div>
```

i tried using outlet component from react router dom but didnt got any help so i am here to get guide from you, wish to get some answers.

Answer (score -1):

firstly cover all of routes with layout

```
<Routes>
    <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
      <Route path="/search/:name" element={<Filter />}/>
      <Route path="/manga/:slug" element={<Manga  />}/>
      <Route path="/read/:slug" element={<Read  />}/>
      <Route path="/all" element={<ViewAll  />}/>
      <Route path="/top" element={<Top  />}/>
    </Route>
</Routes>
```

secondly make sure that you cover your App.jsx in index.js with BrouserRouter

```
 import React from 'react';
 import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
 import './index.css';
 import App from './App';
 import { BrowserRouter as Router , Route , Routes } from 'react-router-dom';

 const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
 root.render(
   <React.StrictMode>
         <Router>
               <Routes>
                 <Route path='/*' element={<App/>}/>
               </Routes>
         </Router>
   </React.StrictMode>
 );
```

Comment: huh what you sayin bro its basic i did it already

Comment: the built of your routes is wrong , you have to built it hierarchical way